# Find all files with os.walk for a specific directory only

Tags: python, os.walk

A directory tree looks like this:

```
DirA--
     |
     -- Map
     |
     -- Fig--
            |
            --file.png
     |
     -- Data--
              |
              -- file.xls
              |
              -- file.csv
```

There are multiple directories, containing multiple files. I would like to get full path to those files that are found in `Data` directory only.

This is what I have so far:

```
dirlist = []
thisdir = os.getcwd()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(thisdir):
    for d in dirs:
        if d.startswith("Data"):
            dirlist.append(os.path.join(root, d))
```

Comment: try `thisdir = os.getcwd() + "/Data"`. And after that loop over file as usual

Comment: thanks, os.getcwd() is pointing to the root, within the root I have several directories Dir1, Dir2, etc and "Data" is a subdirectory. This wont work I am afraid.

Comment: I don't think I understand. getcwd() returns the current working directory of a process, which it the root folder? "Data" folder is in the root?

Comment: sorry @jacobgalam, maybe I am confused myself. Where exactly do you suggest adding it?

Comment: in the start of your code, line 2

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, os.getcwd() is pointing to the directory which contain DirA, DirB, DirC, DirD, each of them may or may not contain Data. The full path would be os.getcwd() + "/DirA" + "/Data". Does it make sense?

Comment: Try my solution. Does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get only Data directory files, you will need to combine `root` and `files`.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(thisdir):
        if "Data" in root: # try using in instead of startswith
           for f in files:
            dirlist.append(os.path.join(root, f))
```

***Trying to do it using 'dirs'***
In case of 'dirs', you don't have access to the files. For example, when `root` is `DirA`, you will have `--Data--` in your `dirs` list but you will have no access to the files of `--Data--` folder.

Comment: this looks very neat, however it returns an empty list. It should be if dirs.startswith("Data"), no?

Comment: No, you can not do that.

Comment: aha, changing root.startswith() to root.endswith() worked! Because --Data-- will be at the end of the path not start

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

rootdir = os.getcwd()

folder_name = "Data"

def get_files(path):
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
    return onlyfiles

def get_search_files(start_path, folder_name):
    for subdir, dirs, files in start_path:
        for x in dirs:
            if x == folder_name:
                data_folder_path = os.path.join(subdir, x)
                dirlist = get_files(data_folder_path)
                return dirlist

dirlist = get_search_files(os.walk(rootdir), folder_name)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives an empty set.

Comment: thanks, I accepted other answer because it is very concise.